# Private Class Variables

Tags: c++

I am having trouble accessing a private class variable in one of my programs. I made this test program but still don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

**test.h**

```
class Test
{
private:
    int Number;
public:
    int Randomize();
};
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include "test.h"
#include <iostream>

int Test::Randomize()
{
    Number == 1;
    std::cout << Number;
    return Number;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "test.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Test test;
    int result = test.Randomize();
    printf ("Number = %d", result);
    return 0;
}
```

I get this warning when compiling

```
test.cpp:6:9: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
        Number == 1;
```

and it is outputting

```
134514363Number = 134514363
```

I have no clue what is going on. Thinking that I am outside its scope maybe. But I mean it is still compiling fine, thought I wouldn't be able to access Number at all if I wasn't doing it right.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: This is pretty much the inverse of mispelling `=` with `==`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`==` is the comparison operator; it returns a `bool` that is `true` if the operands are equal.

`=` is the assignment operator; it assigns the right operand to the left one and returns the first operand (as an lvalue).

So, with `Number == 1` you are telling the compiler "check if `Number` is equal to 1 (and discard the result of such comparison)"; notice that the compiler is warning you about this - he says you that you have an expression without side-effects whose result is discarded, which is obviously a useless instruction and thus "suspect" (hence the warning).

What you want, instead, is `Number = 1`, i.e. "set `Number` to 1".

In other words, the problem here is that you are never assigning a definite value to `Number` in your code (because you misspelled `=`), and `Number` remains at an "indefinite" value (which, in your program, happens to be 134514363, probably due to the garbage left on the stack by the CRT initialization routines).

Comment: Yep really obvious. Thanks XD

Answer (score 3):

`==` is the equality operator, that checks two operands for equality. `=` is the assignment operator, that places the value of its right operand's evaluation in the left operand.

It is giving you a warning (not compiler error) to indicate that `Number == 1;` is not used to do anything, which is very likely to be a mistake of the programmer (e.g. it's asking if you meant to use `=` instead?)

Finally, the reason why you get `134514363` is because in C and C++, if you don't set a variable to anything, it has a random value that you can't predict, based on whatever happened to be in memory there. Basically, C/C++ doesn't initialize variables when they're declared.

In general, compiler warnings are worth reading - they usually mean mistakes in your program.

Answer (score 2):

This line, which is using an `equality` operator, whose result is being discarded hence the warning:

```
Number == 1;
```

should be using `=` which is an `assignment` operator:

```
Number = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You use `==` (comparison) instead of `=` (assignment) here:

```
int Test::Randomize()
{
    Number == 1; // oops!
    std::cout << Number;
    return Number;
}
```

The comparison here does nothing, so a trash value is used when printing.

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing anything with your number, the compiler even warned you. Also, the debugger is your friend.